# Configuring new EJB application using jboss7 server

Tags: ejb-3.0, hibernate-mapping

How to configure ejb with mssql database? I want to access mssql database table using EJB entity beans and i am using jboss 7 as an application server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to:

1. Create a jboss module with your sql server jdbc driver
2. Edit your standalone-xxx.xml and add a datasource, specifying your database username and password. Also, you set your datasource jndi name (which you will use in your persistence.xml of your ejb app)
3. Create a persistence.xml file, and place it in META-INF folder of your ejb app.

Example of persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="SITE_WEB" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/myDataSourceJndiName</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

For creating a module and defining a datasource, checkout https://mpashworth.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/configuring-a-sql-server-data-source-within-jboss-7-1/